# Dynamic reflections in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making my first steps coding with JavaScript and playing with Three.js

I made this experiment using shaders and an environment map (http://jsfiddle.net/gnazoa/3hxrky6k/1/)

Then, with the help of an example of the Three.js site. I learned how to make possible the reflection between the geometries using a cubeCamera (http://jsfiddle.net/gnazoa/z3frkb6m/1/)

Now, the problem is that I can't find a way to make the reflection between the two geometries and the reflection of the textureCube at the same time.

I know that when I am defining my uniforms I can write this:

```
envMap: {
  type: "t",
  value: cubeCamera.renderTarget
},
```

or this:

```
envMap: {
  type: "t",
  value: textureCube
},
```

But this doesn't work:

```
envMap: {
  type: "t",
  value: textureCube, cubeCamera.renderTarget
},
```

Do you have some recomendation? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure, but do you not need two different env maps to reflect multiple items within the scene?  i.e. create a reflection map for each item you want to have separate refelections.

It's worth noting that you must remove the item that is going to have the reflection on it from the scene before updating the reflection map (during an animation cycle) else it ends up as a dark object with no refelection.

Comment: Thank you  @user1236373 it is a good solution but I don't looking for having a different reflection in each item I'm trying to have both reflections (textureCube and cubeCamera.renderTarget) in each item at the same time.

Comment: In other words I'm looking for something like this (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_dynamic2) but without the background image. Only the three geometries, the reflection of the image and the reflection between the geometries.

Answer (score 0):

I think That I found a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/1aoq3n4g/

I repeat each geometry with a reflecting transparent layer. Like this:

```
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { envMap: textureCube, color: 0xffffff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.2, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending} );
```